# Use jQuery to Auto Escape characters from a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

First, I'm not sure I've titled my question properly. Please feel free to correct me if needed.

**My Issue:**

I've created a variable, in jQuery called `var siteTitle`. This variable is available for other .js files to use and then get passed back to the .html page.

It all works great and there are no issues except when the `var siteTitle` will contain certain characters **that need to be escaped**. (quote, single quote, and ampersand to be specific)

What I would like to do is to use a bit of jQuery that would search a particular dom element and see if it is using any of those characters and then automatically escape them.

I've searched for some **similar functions** and can not seem to find exactly what I need ... the closet idea I have seen is something like this. Its not exactly what I need but it is something like what I am looking for.

```
pathto: function(path, file) {
    var rtrim = function(str, list) {
    var charlist = !list ? 's\xA0': (list + '').replace(/([\[\]\(\)\.\?\/\*\{\}\+\$\^\:])/g, '$1');
    var re = new RegExp('[' + charlist + ']+$', 'g');
    return (str + '').replace(re, '');
    };
```

So, I am trying to write a function that will automatically convert those characters to be escaped or their html equivalent.

So, if the `var siteTitle` is used in a dom element like this:

```
<h1 class="titleText">' + siteTitle + '</h1>
```

I need to be able to make sure that any characters get escaped in that element.

Here is a jsFiddle that shows exactly what I am trying to do ... 
https://jsfiddle.net/bbyrdhouse/5jb2fdsr/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are reinventing a wheel: `function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}`. See [*MDN RegExp page*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Please let know if it is not enough.

Comment: I edited my question a bit ...

Comment: sounds like you want JSON.stringify / JSON.parse /  encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent and document.title / document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent

Comment: Nah, none of these seem to work for me ... still searching

Comment: jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bbyrdhouse/5jb2fdsr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jquery, use the `.text()` function to set the value into your HTML. It'll escape it appropriately.

```
var siteTitle = 'My Site "Title"';
$my('.titleText').text(siteTitle);
```

Also, in your fiddle, the `siteTitle` variable is not what you think it is, because the 2nd quotation closes that value since it's not yet escaped. I wrapped it in single quotes in my example.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4eszjr9/)

Comment: that works great, but suppose the site title also has a single quote ... `'My Site's "Title"'`

Comment: @KulerGary That goes back to my comment about the variable being instantiated incorrectly. If the value is being generated somehow (via a server page, jsp, php, etc), you'll need to include that info in your question because that's the point where it needs to be escaped.

Comment: The value is being created dynamically and could be different from page to page ... user to user

Comment: Right, but dynamically how? What's the code that actually prints out the variable's value? It needs to be escaped properly *before* the variable can be instantiated.

Comment: From your updated fiddle, no, there wouldn't be a way because that's invalid javascript. Your variable is set to 'My Site', and then since the variable is closed by the 2nd single quote, the rest of the name is evaluated as code (not a string). See for yourself, view the javascript console when you run your fiddle and you'll see "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: So, one of two possibilities: a) the variable is instantiated differently than your example, and it *is* valid. In which case my solution will work fine. or b) the variable is generated by some sort of server page and needs to be properly escaped for javascript so it doesn't end up with invalid code, as seen in your updated fiddle.

Comment: The user enters the Site Title via a macro string `%site_title%` which gets parsed onto the `index.html` page. I am then adding a variable on the main `index.html` page so that I can use the site title in javascript files and pass it to other pages.

Comment: All works great until the users adds either a quote or double quote depending on which I have used in my variable. I want to pass the contents of the variable to my js file without single quote being escaped.

Comment: I can't tell what language that is since `%...%` is used for many server page languages. But in JSP for example, it would look something like this: `var myEscapedVar = '<%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(pageVar) %>';`